# Weird symbols instead of cyrillic

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular

When I create ASP.NET Core with Angular project:
[image]
and add cyrillic letters to any of angular components, for example to `home.component.html`,  I get something like this:
[image]

I didn't change anything else.
In `_Layout.cshtml` I have `<meta charset="utf-8" />`
Also, I have this problem on other computers.
How to fix it?

Comment: I think we need to see how you added the cyrillic characters.

Comment: share more code showing how you add angular components

Comment: I don't create anything new in this project, It's default asp.net core + angular project.
I just change only small part of html, for example `<h1>Текст</h1>` in `home.component.html`

Comment: Check template html file encoding, it should be utf-8 as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, Angular works totally fine with UTF-8.

I assume you're on Windows OS. If you have Git Bash installed, you can run `file -i <file>` and it will tell you the encoding right away. I believe `text/plain; charset=utf-8` would work best. If you see some other format, simple re-saving with UTF-8 should fix the issue.

---

Example:

```
main@DESKTOP-MRND0KT MINGW64 ~
$ file -i /c/temp/demo*
/c/temp/demo-1.html:  text/plain; charset=utf-8
/c/temp/demo-2.html:  text/plain; charset=us-ascii
/c/temp/demo-3.html:  inode/x-empty; charset=binary
/c/temp/demo-4.html:  text/plain; charset=utf-16le
```

Comment: I changed encoding in all `.ts`, `.cshtml`, `html` from utf-8 without BOM to utf-8 and now, it works correctly. Thank you for answer.